# Does Penicillium roqueforti produce penicyllin?

Tags: microbiology, mycology, antibiotics, food-chemistry

I have recently discovered that blue cheese is produced with *Penicillium roqueforti*. As I know that some *Penicillinum sp.* produce penicyllin I wonder whether it is produced by *P. roqueforti* too?

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penicillium_roqueforti) does not mention penicillin, it mentions *"compounds that can be employed as antibiotics"* instead.

However [the article on *P. glaucum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penicillium_glaucum) also do not mention penicillin, while *P. glaucum* is mentioned in [the article on the history of penicillin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_penicillin).